# C segmentation fault when trying to implement LinkedList

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXN 100
typedef int key;
typedef int data;
struct list * createElement(key k, data info);

struct list{
    key k;
    data info;
    struct list *next;
};
struct list *L;
void init(key k, data info)
{
    L = createElement(k, info);
}
struct list * createElement(key k, data info)
{
    struct list *temp;
    temp = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->k = k;
    temp->info = info;
    return temp;
}
void insert(struct list * element)
{
    element->next = L;
    L = element;
}
void insertBefore(struct list * element, key k)
{
    struct list * currentElement = L;
    while(currentElement != NULL)
    {
        if(currentElement->k == k)
        {
            struct list *temp = currentElement;
            currentElement = element;
            currentElement->next = temp;
            return;
        }
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }

}
void insertAfter(struct list * element, key k)
{
    struct list * currentElement = L;
    while(currentElement != NULL)
    {
        if(currentElement->k == k)
        {
            struct list *temp = currentElement->next;
            currentElement->next = element;
            element->next = temp;
            return;
        }
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
}
void deleteElement(struct list * element)
{
    struct list * currentElement = L;
    while(currentElement != NULL)
    {
        if(currentElement == element)
        {
            struct list * temp = currentElement;
            currentElement = currentElement->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
}
struct list * getElementByKey(key k) {
    printf("\n1");
    struct list *currentElement = L;
    printf("2");
    while(currentElement != NULL)
    {
        printf("3");
        if(currentElement->k == k)
        {
            printf("4");
            return currentElement;
        }
        printf("5");
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
        printf("6");
    }
    printf("There is no such element in the list");
}
struct list * pop()
{
    struct list *element = L;
    L = L->next;
    return element;
}
int main()
{
    init(0, 13);
    struct list * element = createElement(5, 155);
    insert(element);
    struct list * k = createElement(7, 243);
    insert(k);
    //insertBefore(createElement(3, 100), 5);
    printf("The first element value is: %d", pop()->info);
    printf("The second element value is: %d", pop()->info);
    printf("The  element value is: %d", getElementByKey(5)->info);

    return 0;
}
```

So when i execute it the debugger gives me segmantation fault on line 84 which is `if(currentElement->k == k)` on method getElementByKey. I know that i'm trying to access an unexisting element(because i use the pop method and it removes the first element in the list) but it should print me a warning message. it seems that there is a problem in the previous element's key or something that i failed to notice.

Comment: Nice typo in the title, btw ... ;-)

Comment: yes, thanks just noticed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `createElement` function, you forgot to initialize the `next` pointer to NULL.

```
struct list * createElement(key k, data info)
{
    struct list *temp;
    temp = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->k = k;
    temp->info = info;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

So when you're browsing your list, it never finds the last element of the list because next pointer never equals NULL, and goes at some random position in the memory, trying to access to parts it is not allowed to do so.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. I thought the compiler automatically assigns it to NULL and threfore need not write it(I got a PHP backgroud and that's how things work there). That sure gave me a lesson.

Comment: Yes, be sure to initialize everything in C, you can lose a bunch of time debugging a non-initialized variable.

Answer (score 1):

When deleting an element (using `deleteElement()`) you miss to re-initialise `L`.

---

The segmenataion violation in `if(currentElement->k == k)`most likey dues to `currentElement` referring to an invalid memory address. As you test if against `NULL` some lines before line 84, it can only be the case that `currentElement` had either been assigned an invalid address explicitly or the address it points had been freed already.

From the code shown in  `deleteElement()` I assume the latter.

Comment: What do you mean by "When deleting an element (using deleteElement()) you miss to re-initialise L."? I dont have much experience with C and pointers. I am not using the deleteElement method so it's not liked to it this particular error. I will try to see where currentElement links to bad memory

Comment: deleteElement() is not correct, and you'll need to fix it before you use it. Suppose you delete the element to which L points. The entire list is gone because L points to memory that has been free()ed.

Answer (score 1):

two problem

1)at createElement()

need

`temp->next = NULL;`

2)at insertBefore()

not change pointer of list

`currentElement = element;`

e.g)

```
void insertBefore(struct list * element, key k)
{
    struct list * currentElement = L; //add case of L->k
    while(currentElement != NULL)
    {
        if(currentElement->next && currentElement->next->k == k)
        {
            element->next = currentElement->next;
            currentElement->next = element;
            return;
        }
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementByKey():  return value is not determined when not find,.

Comment: This is a good way to implement it, but mine is identical and should work properly.

Comment: @user1113314, do you think when `currentElement = element;` Who is pointing to the `element` ?